# WheelColider в Unity 5 ведёт себя неадекватно

Tags: c#, unity3d

Автомобиль с WheelColider`ами на колёсах улетает в стратосферу. Scale всех колёс и объектов равен 1. Собственно, настройки(Всё по дефолту, кроме радиуса и центра):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Улетает в спящем режиме? Или когда Torque добавляешь?

Comment: В спящем режиме

Comment: массу увеличь у rigidbody

Comment: Стоит 1000. Добавить?

Comment: Вроде должно хватить. Скриншот сделай, настроек rigidbody, машины в целом, и как улетает.

Comment: Видео происходящего - https://vk.com/doc331936034_449906718?hash=47cee14f19ca7cc31f&dl=8c2b9873ee457ff44a

Comment: Больше похоже на то, что на плоскости, на которой стоит машина, нет коллайдера